# Check whether a condition is True for any element of a list (OR operation)

Tags: python, list

The list comprehension `[j-x[i]==0 for i,j in enumerate(x[1:])]` will produce a list of boolean elements. The return value must be a boolean scalar rather than a list. It is obtained by OR-ing all elements. How to do so?

```
def has_same_adjecent(x):
    if len(x)<2:
        return False
    return [j-x[i]==0 for i,j in enumerate(x[1:])]

has_same_adjecent([3,1,3,3])# must return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) (which short circuits). As an additional optimization, you can zip your list with itself shifted by 1, then compare.

```
def has_same_adjecent(data):
     return any(x == y for x, y in zip(data, data[1:]))

has_same_adjecent([3, 1, 3, 3])
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use numpy's [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) as well:

```
np.any(~np.diff(a).astype(bool))
```

**In code**:

```
import numpy as np

a = [3,1,3,3]
print(np.any(~np.diff(a).astype(bool)))

# True
```

Comment: Numpy is a wonderful module, but a bit of an overkill for a simple operation like this.

Comment: @cs95, fairly agree. A note to OP:  this works for lists with numerical values only.